# Creation table with php

Tags: php, mysql, html

i have a problem with the 'create table' in PHP. The name of table is the name of the user registered. The problem is in '$nuovidati'. The registration script work but doesn't create table.....

Code:

```
    <?php
    require('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['registra']))
    {
        $user = (isset($_POST['user'])) ? trim($_POST['user']) : '';
        $pass = (isset($_POST['pass'])) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : '';
        $mail = (isset($_POST['mail'])) ? trim($_POST['mail']) : '';
        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $user = addslashes($user);
            $pass = addslashes($pass);
            $mail = addslashes($mail);
        }
        if(strlen($user) < 4 || strlen($user) > 12)
            die('Nome Utente troppo corto, o troppo lungo');
        elseif(strlen($pass) < 4 || strlen($pass) > 12)
            die('Password troppo corta, o troppo lunga');
        elseif(!eregi("^[a-z0-9][_\.a-z0-9-]+@([a-z0-9][0-9a-z-]+\.)+([a-z]{2,4})", $mail))
            die('Email non valida');
        elseif(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT user FROM utenti WHERE user = '$user' LIMIT 1")) == 1)
            die('Nome Utente non disponibile');
        elseif(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mail FROM utenti WHERE mail = '$mail' LIMIT 1")) == 1)
            die('Questo indirizzo email risulta gi&agrave; registrato ad un altro utente');
        else
        {
            $pass = md5($pass);
            $strSQL = "INSERT INTO utenti (user,pass,mail)";
            $strSQL .= "VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$mail')";
            mysql_query($strSQL) OR die("Errore 003, contattare l'amministratore ".mysql_error());
            $index = 'modello.php';
            copy($index, $user) or die("Errore copia.");
            $rin = basename($user, ".php").".php";
            rename($user, $rin);
    $nuovidati = "CREATE TABLE ".$user."
    (
           descrizione varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
           data date NOT NULL,
           entrata varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
           uscita varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
           saldo varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
           id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    )";
mysql_query($nuovidati) OR die("Erroe: ".mysql_error());
            header('Location: registrato.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the working code:

```
$nuovidati = "CREATE TABLE $user 
(
        descrizione varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        data date NOT NULL,
        entrata varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
        uscita varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
        saldo varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        primary key (id)
)"; 
mysql_query($nuovidati) OR die("Errore: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Remove the quotes and dots around `".$user."` --- `CREATE TABLE $user`

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use MD5 for password storage; it's old and considered too "fast". Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. Plus, `eregi()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: It seems like you're not executing it or setting the variable to execute it. Try removing `$nuovidati = ` or use `if($$nuovidati){...}`

Comment: I add: mysql_query($nuovidati) OR die("Erroe: ".mysql_error());

Comment: Did doing that work? If not, what error(s) is it showing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like a SQL error, try this:

```
"CREATE TABLE $user
(
   id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   descrizione varchar(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   data date NOT NULL,
   entrata varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
   uscita varchar(10000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   saldo varchar(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";
```